# How to bundle undo steps in Modal operator

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, operator

Background info: I am creating an addon with an 'Editor' mode. The mode is initiated by an Operator, and while the Modal is running, the user can add/remove/edit objects in the scene. The modal ends when the user toggles a boolean, exiting the 'Editor' mode.

Goal: I would like to bundle all actions that the user takes while in 'Editor' mode into one undo step once the editor is exited.

Question: Is there a way to achieve this goal in Python using Blender's undo system?

I've tried adding 'UNDO' to the `bl_options` property of the operator, but this only bundles the operations done in the `execute` function. I am currently using `bpy.ops.ed.undo_push(message="Edit Assets")` to push a step to the undo stack when the modal 'Editor' state is exited, but there are many steps left over in the undo stack from where the user added/removed objects in 'Editor' mode.